# Множественный catch

Tags: java, исключения

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            method1();
            method2();
            method3();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Null");
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Arith");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Array");
        }
    }

    public static void method1() {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 0;
        System.out.println(a / b);
    }

    public static void method2() {
        int[] array = new int[2];
        array[5] = 10;
    }

    public static void method3() {
        String s = null;
        String m = s.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Почему не отрабатывает программа? То есть почему только Arith в консоли я вижу? Потому что "выбран" method1? Чтобы такой код отработал каждый метод должен быть в отдельном try catch блоке?

Comment: Да. В отдельном. Либо в кетч вызывать

Comment: Нет. Можно продолжить выполнение после обработки исключения.

Comment: но дальше код не выполняется-то

Comment: @RomanC можете пожалуйста написать пример который покажет как правильно решить данную проблему, то есть как правильно обработать эти 3 метода

Answer (score 2):

В try вы располагаете блок кода

```
method1();
method2();
method3();
```

Как только в этом коде выбрасывается исключение, весь блок кода останавливаеся и переходит в бок catch

Если хотите продолжать работу даже когда method1 бросил исключение - делайте для него отдельный try

```
try {
     method1();
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
     System.out.println("Arith");
}

try {
     method2();
     method3();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
     System.out.println("Null");
}  catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
     System.out.println("Array");
}
```

Ну и методы 2 и 3 тоже разносим на разные try блоки, если хотим выполнить каждый из них в любом случае. А еще лучше проверять корректность введенных аргументов внутри функции, но это уже другая история